# Compiling 64 bit qt (from source) using cmake on windows

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I failed to compile qt shared library(64 bit) on windows using various versions of cmake. I think am making some mistakes in selecting cmake options. Can any one point me to some tutorials or tell the steps to be followed. Thanks in advance. (I can't use visual studio for this.)

Comment: Qt doesn't use cmake. You have to call configure.bat.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/2011/02/01/how-to-compile-qt-4-7-with-visual-studio-2010/#comment-6641) worked for me :

```
@ECHO OFF
rmdir /Q /S C:\Qt\qt-git-build
mkdir C:\Qt\qt-git-build
cd C:\Qt\qt-git-build
..\qt-git\configure -opensource -mp -qt-zlib
nmake
nmake qdoc3
editbin /STACK:0x200000 bin\qdoc3.exe
nmake docs
nmake install
nmake clean
cd ..
```

Comment: But it uses visual studio. I can't use visual studio.

Comment: rwik: mingw build should work similar, add -platform win32-g++ to configure.bat and call mingw32-make instead of nmake.